# Rendering cursive fonts

Tags: opengl, graphics, fonts, rendering

I have some experience rendering text in opengl, where the approach is to use font glyphs (which can eb created through things like freetype) and then used by pulling individual lettings useing texture coordinates, however I wanted to try using a more create font and was thinking about how to render cursive fonts. 
I noticed a lot of the fonts on here are cursive fonts and have been unable to find any information on rendering cursive fonts. I realize that a texture lookup approach will probably not work in the same way. I am looking for some advice to point in a direction since I have ben unable to find one.

https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/list/popular

The only thing I can think about is to come up with a set of bezier curves to represent the entire sentence and then render it. This would make it hard to render text dynamically since the curves will need to be connected in real time to maintain smoothness.

Has anyone had any success with rendering cursive fonts?

Comment: You may want to look at how "cursive fonts" work typographically speaking.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I think that this is actually a really interesting problem. Best to avoid taking short cuts here.

Answer (score 2):

Cursive fonts work in the same way as non-cursive fonts do. The only thing is that the axis-aligned bounding boxes of neighboring glyphs might overlap. In theory, this can happen to any font - not only to cursive ones.

A glyph is not only characterized by its width and height. It also has additional information that are used for laying out text. In FreeType, these are bearings and advance distances (see the [documentation](https://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/glyphs/glyphs-3.html#section-3)). The advance distance tells you how much the text cursor will advance, i.e., where the next glyph will start. The bearing will tell you how much space you have to leave blank between the current text cursor and the actual glyph. For very skewed glyphs, this bearing might be negative, i.e., the glyph starts left of the cursor position. Similarly, the advance distance may be smaller than the glyph width. This allows neighboring glyphs to intertwine.

Btw, different APIs call these font metrics differently. E.g., DirectWrite calls them overhangs.

Comment: I spent some time reading about cursive fonts and this seems to make sense. Just to make sure I understand, for cursive fonts each letter may have multiple versions, and then there becomes a matching between which version of the letters to use. It would make sense for this to allow for things like negative alignment to correctly position the letters next to each other.

Comment: Well, there may be different font styles (such as regular, bold, italic). Other than that, there are usually not multiple versions for letters. Just pick an arbitrary cursive font and type some text in a text editor of your choice. The letters will always look the same.

Answer (score 1):

Effectively what you have to do is define a relationship between characters, and use visual variations of the same characters so that they appear linked.

For example, a cursive lowercase 'L' next to a cursive lowercase 'O' will link from the bottom of the L to the top of the O; whereas if the letter after the L was, let's say 'i', then it would have to link the characters at the bottom.

If you're intending on some predetermined text, then you can of course also just manually arrange things. If you're looking for a real-time solution, you would need the above method.

Take a loot at [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_text_layout) and perhaps some of the libraries found in the "implementations" section, which should point you in the direction of ready-to-use assets.